# /etc/sudoers.d/ broken user access

Tags: linux, root, sudo

I made an oops and tried to create a reboot privilege file in sudoers.d, the user indicated is wrong and I cant delete the file now or do any sudo commands.

```
Dodebian@beaglebone:~$ sudo rm /etc/sudoers.d/reboot_privilege
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/reboot_privilege: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/reboot_privilege near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
debian@beaglebone:~$
```

does anyone know how to fix this..

Comment: Can always live boot a rescue image and delete it from there

Comment: What @NeilLocketz said: boot of a rescue disk (into rescue mode?) and delete the file. For future reference: **don't** use *nano* (or your other preferred editor) to edit sudoers files. For the main file, `/etc/sudoers`, do `visudo` and `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/<file>` for others ... this will stop you from saving files that will lock you out of using `sudo` ;)

Comment: Another technique is to have two login sessions into the computer, with both of them sudo'ed to root, before you change the sudo config.  Then, when you exit/disconnect one of them to test the new config, the other already has root privileges ready to fix a problem in the config.